# Software traps vs Hardware Traps

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

Based on my understanding, the basic difference between traps and interrupts is that the traps are synchronous and generated by exceptions (div by zero etc) while the interrupts are asynchronous(Multiple devices could try to interrupt at the same time although who wins the race is the one who acquires the lock to the work queue first). There are two types of interrupts : hardware and software. The div by zero exception is detected by the hardware and therefore that serves as an example for hardware traps.

I have two questions here.

1. Is my understanding about the schemes correct and are there any more differences?
2. Is there a thing called software trap? If so, An example would be helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `syscall` instruction could be considered a software trap.  It causes all the elements of trap/interrupt handling (context switch to an interrupt service routine which executes fully privileged) but is triggered under software control.

Interrupts are not completely asynchronous either, since masking and unmasking occurs synchronously.  Thus although no two asynchronous event can occur at exactly the same time, multiple interrupts can be unmasked at exactly the same time, in which case interrupt priorities, not order of occurrence, control servicing order.

Comment: I had been imagining syscall to be a software interrupt.. for some wierd reasons!! what would you cite as an example for software interrupt?

Comment: @Karthick: All software instructions are synchronous, therefore according to your distinction between trap and interrupt, it would be classified as a trap.

Comment: true.. sys calls could be argued to be traps... I had been imagining syscall to be a software interrupt.. for some wierd reasons!! Could you please cite as an example for software interrupt? And what would be your answer if I ask you for the difference between an interrupt and trap? does this sound good "multiple interrupts could occur at the same time but only one trap at a time"? or maybe "hardware interrupts are generated by devices itself while the hardware traps are those generate because of the software that runs on the devices?"

Comment: "interrupts are generated by external stimuli".  As I said, "software interrupts" are synchronous and internally generated, so they would be classified as traps.  The term "software interrupt" implies that no distinction is being drawn between interrupts and traps.

Comment: do interrupts generate traps to enforce a context switch?

Comment: @Karthick: Interrupts and traps both cause a context switch, and context switching is synchronized to the CPU fetch-decode-execute cycle.  Most CPUs architectures have an exception vector, which is an array of addresses of service routines, although some architectures have just a single handler along with an exception information register, in such systems the software is responsible for vectoring depending on which interrupt occurred.  And you can have a hybrid, like the PC/AT IRQs controller, where many IRQs are mapping to one CPU interrupt, so that handler has to re-vector to another ISR.